# Fading/highlighting in D3 cluster force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, highlight, force-layout

I am working on [this `D3` force layout with clusters example](http://jsfiddle.net/LjsnD/):

[image]

I would like to highlight only nodes of the current cluster on mouse hovering a node (other clusters should fade to opacity 0.1).

What would be your approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I first wrote this function for comparison of two nodes' clusters:

```
function isSameCluster(a, b) {
     return a.cluster == b.cluster;
};
```

Than, a function fade() that uses the function above: (it is meant to be called for any value of the argument "opacity")

```
function fade(opacity) {
    return function(d) {
        node.style("stroke-opacity", function(o) {
                thisOpacity = isSameCluster(d, o) ? 1 : opacity;
                this.setAttribute('fill-opacity', thisOpacity);
                return thisOpacity;
            });
    };
};
```

After that, this is how I linked mouse hover and function fade():

```
.on("mouseover", fade(.1))
.on("mouseout", fade(1));
```

The result is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/47J4w/):

[image]